# Why does getPropertyValue return an empty string instead of the element's style property?

Tags: javascript, css

This seems to only happen when I use "background" in the parameters of `getPropertyValue();`:

```
var d = document.getElementById('myDiv');

window.getComputedStyle(d).getPropertyValue('background'); // ""
```

Why does it return an empty string and how can I get this to return the actual background css property?

Comment: This behaviour persists in IE11 and FF 36.01 but Chrome 40.0.2214.115 works as expected and returns the assembled short-hand style.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CSSStyleDeclaration), at least the mozilla browser returns `null` when requesting the value of [shorthand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Guide_to_Shorthand_CSS). So it seems have to query the different properties of the background style separately:

```
window.getComputedStyle(d).getPropertyValue('background-color');
window.getComputedStyle(d).getPropertyValue('background-image');
// etc.
```

**Edit:** it looks like it is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=137688)